# How to group database catalogs and schemas using JDBC?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, metadata

I am aware that catalogs and schemas are not the same in all databases. In some databases what is known as schema is treated as catalog and in some others the opposite.

In some databases both catalogs and schemas information is available.

I am using the following code to obtain schemas

```
            result = databaseMetaData.getSchemas();
            schemaList = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (result.next()) {
                schemaList.add(result.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"));
            }
```

And for catalogs,

```
            result = databaseMetaData.getCatalogs();
            catalogs = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (result.next()) {
                catalogs.add(result.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
            }
```

In such cases I want to group the schemas which belong to a particular catalog. But I couldn't get the API. How to do it?

I have tried with the following too. Here the result set is empty.

```
ResultSet metaDataSchemas = metaData.getSchemas(null, null);
```

Comment: A bit awkward but `getColumns` will do.

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried with all null parametes. But empty resultset.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @user1183179 Not a particular database. I am working with all systems.

Comment: No results is a bit strange; try another DB first. Maybe rights?

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried with all dbs like mysql, sqlserver, postgres.

Comment: I cannot try it out this week; I personally never used only nulls, but worked per catalog I think.

Answer (score 0):

you were so close try

```
  result = databaseMetaData.getSchemas();

        while (result.next()) {
         String catalog= result.getString(2);
        }
```

Comment: The answer is not enough to solve the problem of grouping. I have tried already.

Comment: @BRS a simple question, how do you intend to use the grouped data?, for example if its getAllSchemas("myCat"); or something like that, its easy and can be done using a map, arrays or whatever,  I just want to make sure  that I provide the right answer.